# How to configure NERDTree to expand specific folders by default?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I find that when I work on a code project, as soon as I open NERDTree to navigate, I have to expand the lib/ , web/ and web/controllers/ directories, where all the action is.  I'd love to have that happen automatically based on a .nerdtreerc, like

```
# ~/code/myproject/.nerdtreerc
send-keys o lib
send-keys o web
send-keys o web/controllers
```

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 0):

NERDTree allows to hook into the creation of the tree via a User `:autocmd`, like this:

```
autocmd User NERDTreeInit global/lib/normal o
```

The `:global` command locates all lines containing `lib`, and then emulates the `o` command. (For me, this only worked on the first instance though.)